# Where should assets be stored in a Symfony project?

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

The "[Official Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/best_practices/web-assets.html)" states:

> Symfony developers have traditionally stored these assets in the `Resources/public/` directory of each bundle.

and mentions as "Best Practice":

> Store your assets in the `web/` directory.

So we can understand that unless before, when assets was stored in bundles, we have now to store them in `web/`.

**But are we talking about source files or complied/minified files?**

A little later in the text, the documentation rightly points out:

> Keep in mind that `web/` is a public directory and that anything stored here will be publicly accessible. For that reason, you should put your compiled web assets here, but not their source files (e.g. SASS files).

#### So, my questions:

**1)** Should we still store the assets source files (not compiled/minimized) in bundles? If yes, where?

**2)** Is the `Resources/public` directory really publicly accessible or just accessible by Assetic to minify and copy assets to `web/`?

The chapter "[How to Use Assetic for Asset Management](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/assetic/asset_management.html)" states:

> But with Assetic, you can manipulate these assets however you want (or load them from anywhere) before serving them.

**3)** So, is the `Resources/public` directory still relevant?

**4)** Why use a public folder like [in this example](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files):

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

if Assetic would be able to read files from `AppBundle/Resources/assets/js`?

**5)** About source files related to all bundles, where to put them? It seems even the [Symfony team wondered about that](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/issues/5).

Comment: You can keep source files in your bundle. I do it, and use a service to compile/minify my assets into the `web/` directory. The `app/Ressources/` shouldb't be public, as there is a `.htaccess` file in the `app/` folder which deny access. And last, it's not recommanded anymore to use assetic bundle. There is a built-in function to use assets since Symfony 2.8. [How to Minify CSS/JS Files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/uglifyjs.html) / [Web Assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) / [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic.html)

Comment: I agree, this is confusing indeed. :|